# “Error getting chaincode package bytes” in car-lease-demo deploy via REST-chaincodeID path

Tags: github, ibm-cloud, blockchain, hyperledger-fabric

I'm trying to deploy car-lease-demo in Bluemix Services and I cant find the right path for chaincodeID in swaggerApi. I've used the [github repo from IBM](https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/car-lease-demo/blob/master/Chaincode/src/vehicle_code/vehicles.go) but it outputs this error:

```
{
    "jsonrpc": "2.0",
    "error": {
        "code": -32001,
        "message": "Deployment failure",
        "data": "Error when deploying chaincode: Error getting chaincode package bytes: Error getting code 'go get' failed with error: \"exit status 1\"\npackage github.com/IBM-Blockchain/car-lease-demo/Chaincode/vehicle_code: cannot find package \"github.com/IBM-Blockchain/car-lease-demo/Chaincode/vehicle_code\" in any of:\n\t/opt/go/src/github.com/IBM-Blockchain/car-lease-demo/Chaincode/vehicle_code (from $GOROOT)\n\t/opt/gopath/_usercode_/798513695/src/github.com/IBM-Blockchain/car-lease-demo/Chaincode/vehicle_code (from $GOPATH)\n\t/opt/gopath/src/github.com/IBM-Blockchain/car-lease-demo/Chaincode/vehicle_code\n"
    },
    "id": 3
}
```

I've found this 
[source](http://go-search.org/view?id=github.com%2FIBM-Blockchain%2Fcar-lease-demo%2FChaincode%2Fvehicle_code) and checked the JSON tab but the package that is referred in the beginning is not working.

Any idea which is the correct path for the chaincodeID to deploy car-lease-demo chaincode in BMX?

I'm using BMX v0.6

Comment: Both [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40208148/1270789) and [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/40646412/1270789) offer solutions to a similar problem.

Comment: I've seen this answers but I think there should be a specific path for car-lease-demo. I've also deployed "learn-chaincode" example without an error and the version of BMX that I'm using should not be a problem for the error that I am getting I think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it says in the error message the `go get <chaincode path>` failed during the chaincode deploy. This is because the chaincode `path` in your deploy request is wrong. The correct chaincode path for this chaincode is:

```
github.com/IBM-Blockchain/car-lease-demo/Chaincode/src/vehicle_code
```

That said, before you try deploying a chaincode from the web in this manner, you can check if the go chaincode is accessible over the web by doing a:

```
go get <public chaincode path>
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer :) Can you tell me where or how did you find the right path? I've found the path that I was using from this [link](http://go-search.org/view?id=github.com%2Fhyperledger%2Ffabric%2Fcore%2Fchaincode%2Fshim) , number 4 package on the list...

Comment: The code is on github... so found it here https://github.com/IBM-Blockchain/car-lease-demo/tree/master/Chaincode/src/vehicle_code. I just tested the path with `go get`